# Plotting building footprints with leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, polygon

Microsoft shared data on [US building footprints](https://github.com/Microsoft/USBuildingFootprints) I am trying to visualize it with R/Leaflet.

```
dc_buildings <- geojsonio::geojson_read("DistrictofColumbia.geojson", what = "sp")
plot(dc_buildings)
```

gives me a working, but primitive solution

[image]

But I need to use addPolygons at Leaflet to make it more fancy.

But when I am trying to check the names of the spatialpolygondataframe, it give me only

```
> names(dc_buildings)
[1] "FID"
```

I think I need to use a different function to access the names, probably with @data.
Then I will be able to

```
leaflet(dc_buildings) %>%
addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>$
addPolygons()
```

and somehow visualize this buildings.

My desired outcome - the map of DC similar to this [NYT visualization](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2018/10/12/us/map-of-every-building-in-the-united-states.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it and I did it pretty easily.

```
dc_buildings <- st_read("DistrictofColumbia.geojson")
dc_map <- leaflet() %>%
addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
addPolygons(data = dc_buildings, color = "black", opacity = 1)
```

[image]

However, the file is big and everything is slow, other US states are even more bigger and laptop crashes. If somebody can advise how to make it more effective, please do.